# PHP base64_decode yields invalid image file

Tags: php, base64

my problem:

I am saving an uploaded base64 string to a file using PHP. This string comes from an iPhone app and is a base64 encoded jpeg file.

When I take the contents of this file and add it manually to a data src in an image tag, it displays CORRECTLY. When I read it using file_get_contents and add the resulting string to an img data tag, it works CORRECTLY.

My issue: when I read the file using file_get_contents and save the results using base64_decode(), the resulting jpeg file is *INVALID*.

**My question is, why does the obviously valid base64 encoded string not yield a valid JPEG file when decoded and saved?**

Some source excerpts:

This functions as it should, outputs the image:

```
$imagepath = "D:\\path\\to\\image\\mybase64image.txt";
$imagecontent = file_get_contents($imagepath);
header("Content-type:text/html");
$d = '<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $imagecontent . '"/>';
echo $d;
```

This, does NOT work and the file is invalid:

```
$imagepath = "D:\\path\\to\\image\\mybase64image.txt";
$imagecontent = file_get_contents($imagepath);
file_put_contents('img.jpg', base64_decode($imagecontent));
```

-- img.jpg is an invalid file. 
The paths are valid, the file is there, permissions are there as well (the resulting file img.jpg is a binary file, just invalid)  and as I said, it works as a data src.

Here is the base64 encoded file:

http://www.mailnet.de/7E072017-DAEB-41E1-B02E-23FB51A05B80.txt

- PHP version is 5.3.8 using FASTCGI
- OS is Windows 2008 R2
- Web server is IIS 7.5

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code that encodes and saves the data?

Comment: if you mean the iPhone code, no I don't have access to that. I can post the base64 encoded file if that helps?

Comment: Ok, edited - added a link to the base64 encoded file.

Comment: @onetrickpony - please enter an answer with that suggestion, it's correct and solved my problem. Such a dumb thing to miss. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` characters are not allowed in the b64 set. It looks like your string is url-encoded. [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it before passing it to `base64_decode()`.

It works in the browser like it is because they always decode url attributes.